# Print output to separate text files

Tags: python-3.x

The script below opens devices.csv and reads the rows, then prints 2 of the fields.  I want to create a separate .txt file for each row using 'Host Name' field, then print 'Configuration Text' to each file.

```
import csv
import sys
import os
path = 'C:/configs'
fh = "C:/configs/devices.csv"
with open(fh, mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        print(row['Host Name'], row['Configuration Text'])
```

Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv
import sys
import os
path = 'C:/configs'
fh = "C:/configs/devices.csv"
with open(fh, mode='r') as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        with open(os.path.join(path, row['Host Name']), "w") as outfile:     #Create File with host name
            outfile.write(row['Configuration Text'])     #Write Content
```

Comment: This works.  However, how can I specify the path where these txt files will live?

Comment: Use `os.path.join(path, row['Host Name'])`